# One table column too much on loaded Excel Document in PHP

Tags: php, html, loops, html-table, phpexcel

I made an Script, where you can insert an Excel Document and it will be shown as table on a website. But there is one bug, between every loaded table column is an extra column.

This is my example Excel File:
[Excel Example File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yuxj3.png)

And this is my Browser Output, wehn I load an Excel Document, where you can see there is a column too much:
[Browser-Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryJdW.png)
I marked the extra column's that are too much, when you compare the output with the file, you can see that in the original fils isn't a empty column between the Words.

This is the code I use (im also using PHPExcel), the table is generated in the two foreach loops:

--------------------------------index.php---------------------------------

```
    <?php
  require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

  if (isset($_FILES['excelFile']) && !empty($_FILES['excelFile']['tmp_name']))
  {
     $excelObject = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['excelFile']['tmp_name']);
     $getSheet = $excelObject->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null);

     echo "<table>";
     $rundeAnzahl = 0;
     foreach ($getSheet as  $zeile) {
         echo "<tr>";

         $x = 0;
         foreach ($getSheet as $item)
         {
           echo "<td>". @$getSheet[$rundeAnzahl][$x] . "<td>";
           $x = $x + 1;
         }
         echo "</tr>";
         $rundeAnzahl += 1;
     }
  }

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Excel Tabelle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="excelFile" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Can you please help me, and find out why this extra column is showing up?

Comment: you should edit your question, including the code, so it would be easier to copy and paste and try it for someone who reads it. i dont understand the problem, in your xls it counts from 0 to 5 in your result it counts only to 3. maybe your second foreach($getSheet as $item) should be a foreach($zeile as $item)

Comment: btw you shouldnt use @ to surpress error mesages, try a if(isset($var))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your inner `foreach` you are never closing the `<td>` but, instead, creating another column. Change it to read:

```
foreach ($getSheet as $item) {
    echo "<td>". @$getSheet[$rundeAnzahl][$x] . "</td>";
    $x = $x + 1;
}
```